# Selenium webdriver can't find elements at chrome://downloads

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use selenium with the chromedriver in python.

My problem is that selenium gives me an error as i try to access elements on the chrome download page (chrome://downloads). 
For example i try to get the file url "http://file.jpg".

```
<a id="url" target="_blank" href="http://file.jpg">http://file.jpg</a>
```

But as i try to get the element by its id I get an exception.

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("chrome://downloads/")
file_url = driver.find_element_by_id("url").get_attribute("href")
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 3, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id("url")
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 269, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"url"}
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
```

Using javascript via `driver.execute_script()` didn't work for me either.
Why am i getting a `NoSuchElementException` when i can see the element in the browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Target link located inside several `shadow-root` blocks. Try this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("chrome://downloads/")

manager = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body/deep/downloads-manager')
item = manager.find_element_by_css_selector('body/deep/downloads-item')
shadow = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot;', item)
link = shadow.find_element_by_css_selector('div#title-area>a')

file_url = link.get_attribute("href")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, exactly what i was looking for. (Just needed to change "css-selector" to "css_selector")

Comment: oh, yep. missed that:)