# How to access elements under `shadow-root` at 'chrome://downloads' using jquery and selenium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, selenium

I am trying to get the name of the last downloaded file in my selenium javascript application.

I have my selenium driver navigating to the chrome downloads page using: `driver.get('chrome://downloads');` , but when I get there, selenium is not able to find ANY elements on the download page.

The chrome downloads page *'chrome://downloads'* has a bunch of **`shadow-root`** elements that I don't know how to get underneath in order to access the id's that I want. **How do I access identifiers beneath `shadow-root` items?**

I want to get $("#file-link") as shown here:

[image: showing file link id]

But when I use jquery to find it, everything returns null (probably because it's behind `shadow-root`)

[image: jquery actions return null]
[image: jquery actions return null 2]

Here's a big picture of all the information I have including showing that "#file-link" totally exists:

[image: html structure of chrome download page]

The code I am using to wait for the element to exist is the same that I use for all elements in my application, so I think this is already working:

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('downloads-manager')), 120000).then(function(){
    console.log("#downloads-manager shows");
    driver.findElement(By.id('downloads-manager')).then(function(dwMan){
        //How do I "open" #shadow-root now? :(
    });
});
```

**Here is my version information:**

- Chromium v54.0.2840.71
- Node v6.5.0
- ChromeDriver v2.27.440175
- selenium-webdriver v3.4.0

**Similar Question**

- [Selenium webdriver can't find elements at chrome://downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468715/selenium-webdriver-cant-find-elements-at-chrome-downloads) (This is the same problem I am having but in python)

**Links**

- Selenium Javascript API: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$` from your example is not a shorthand for `JQuery`.
It's function overridden by the page to locate an element by id only:

```
function $(id){var el=document.getElementById(id);return el?assertInstanceof(el,HTMLElement):null}
```

To select through the shadow DOM, you need to use the '/deep/' combinator.

So to get all the links in the download page:

```
document.querySelectorAll("downloads-manager /deep/ downloads-item /deep/ [id=file-link]")
```

And with Selenium:

```
By.css("downloads-manager /deep/ downloads-item /deep/ [id=file-link]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not check the downloads folder directly? I do this for downloading Excel files. I first clear the downloads folder, click the button to download the file, wait ~5 sec (varies by file size, internet speed, etc.), and then looking in the folder for a "*.xlsx" file. This also has the benefit of working with any browser.

C# Examples:

```
/// <summary>
/// Deletes the contents of the current user's "Downloads" folder
/// </summary>
public static void DeleteDownloads()
{
    // Get the default downloads folder for the current user
    string downloadFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\Downloads";
    // Delete all existing files
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
    foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
    {
        dir.Delete(true);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Looks for a file with the given extension (Example: "*.xlsx") in the current user's "Download" folder.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Empty string if files are found</returns>
public static string LocateDownloadedFile(string fileExtension)
{
    // Get the default downloads folder for the current user
    string downloadFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\Downloads";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(downloadFolderPath);
    FileInfo[] filesFound = di.GetFiles(fileExtension);
    if (filesFound.Length == 0)
    {
        return "No files present";
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And then in my Test I can `Assert.IsEmpty(LocateDownloadedFile);` This way if the assert fails, the error message if printed.

> Expected: String.Empty.
>   Actual: No files present.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that might be a better approach. I think there is a variable for where chrome downloads all the user's files, so I could just check to see if there was a file downloaded there recently. I'll try this method and see if it's easier to get working :)