# VBA Selenium Chromedriver save PDF

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

This link is a PDF file that opens in Chrome  [PDF file](https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf3/53/5221/522008-haier/washing_machine.pdf?b76112ef24159605ca8df71689bce0a7).
Can I somehow save this PDF file from this page?
I run chrome with such settings

```
driver.SetPreference "download.default_directory", "c:\chr"
driver.SetPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True
driver.SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False
```

but when you press CONTROL + S, the save as window still appears.
May be i can download PDF directly from Chrome?

UPDATE CODE:

This works fine:

```
Public Sub browser_open()


Set driver = New ChromeDriver

driver.SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False
driver.AddArgument "--kiosk-printing"

driver.Start "chrome"
driver.get "https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf3/53/5221/522008-haier/washing_machine.pdf?b76112ef24159605ca8df71689bce0a7"

driver.SendKeys keys.ArrowDown
driver.SendKeys keys.ArrowDown, keys.ArrowLeft
```

But if i want to press "CONTROL + S":

```
driver.SendKeys keys.Control, "s"
```

nothing happens.

Comment: It is a website url rather than a direct download link. If you intend to download via pressing download in chrome it is in shadow-root and will need API interfaces. See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52906215/6241235

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to work with your example, but ```.SendKeys keys.Control, "s"``` is not work for me on this PDF page [link](https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf3/53/5221/522008-haier/washing_machine.pdf?b76112ef24159605ca8df71689bce0a7), after ```.SendKeys keys.Control, "s"``` Save as dialog is not open

Comment: Have you got the right window handle?

Comment: I have only one Chrome window. I'm updated my code. Where is my error?

Comment: I meant using the solution in the link I sent. You can't interact with the print pdf via shadow-root without API call

Comment: But  ```driver.SendKeys keys.Control, "s" ``` it should work without resorting to the API?

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for my English, I use Google Translate.

This command runs a script that creates a link element to save the page as a pdf file, and then simulates clicking on the link.

```
driver.ExecuteScript "var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = '" & driver.url & "'; a.download = 'My file.pdf'; document.body.appendChild(a); a.click();"
```

Below is the full code:

```
Public Sub browser_open()

Set driver = New ChromeDriver

driver.SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False
driver.AddArgument "--kiosk-printing"

driver.Start "chrome"
driver.Get "https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf3/53/5221/522008-haier/washing_machine.pdf?b76112ef24159605ca8df71689bce0a7"
driver.ExecuteScript "var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = '" & driver.url & "'; a.download = 'My file.pdf'; document.body.appendChild(a); a.click();"
```

Note!
It may take a few seconds for the download to begin.

Note!
To download multiple files you need to confirm this in the popup window, I do not know how to do this programmatically.

Comment: This part doesn't work, a.download = 'My file.pdf';
Is there a way we can make it download to a different path?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work", does the file download?  Do you just want to set a different download location?