# Downloading PDF document in Chrome using VBA Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, download, selenium-chromedriver

I currently need to download multiple PDF files from a specific website.

Once I reach to this point the usual action is to click on the save button or to type "CTRL + S"

[Click on Save button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890015/vba-ie-automation-save-as-pdf-isnt-working/52906215#52906215)

I retrieved this on [this post of IE Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890015/vba-ie-automation-save-as-pdf-isnt-working/52906215#52906215)

But I'm trying to excecute the download action with the following code:

```
bot.SendKeys Keys.Control, "s"
```

And is not working.

How can I make this work on Chrome?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to download the pdfs.

```
   Dim PDF_URL as string

   #If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr

#Else
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If



Private Sub File_Download()
    Dim FileURL As String
    Dim DestinationFile As String
    FileURL = PDF_URL
    DestinationFile = "C:\PDFs\PDFName.pdf"
    If URLDownloadToFile(0, FileURL, DestinationFile, 0, 0) = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "File downloaded started"
    Else
        Debug.Print "File downloaded not started"
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub GetURL
  PDF_URL = Chrome_Driver.FindElementById("EleID").Attribute("src")
  File_Download
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of websites that may not allow bots. You should go to the website's /robots.txt to see if there are any restrictions on bots pulling the content you are trying to grab. These sections will show "disallow" anything bots are forbidden to access.

example: google/robots.txt

Yes, websites can even tell if you are using Selenium.