# How to switch to iframe inside shadow dom with selenium

Tags: selenium, iframe, webview, webdriver, shadow-dom

Application under test is based on Electron (version 9.1.1) written as desktop application for Linux.
In electron there are custom tag `<webview>` that is quote ["The webview tag is essentially a custom element using shadow DOM to wrap an iframe element inside it."](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#internal-implementation)

I can access shadow dom and get iframe as `WebElement` out of it with Java selenim(version 3.141.59).

But swithcing to iframe still left me on parent context.

And my question is:

**HOW TO SWITH TO IFRAME INSIDE SHADOW DOM?**

```
//getting webdriver
WebDriver driver = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

//acquire shadow dom WebElement 
WebElement shadowDom = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", driver.findElement(By.tagName("webview")));

//acquire iframe WebElement 
WebElement iframe = shadowDom.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));

//trying to swith to iframe inside shadow DOM, but still at parent context because can't find element that exist in iframe
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

//obviously produce NoSuchElementException
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[text()='Columns']"));
```

---

This is HTML of the page, and I can get html of `webview` executing in devtools command `document.querySelector('webview').openDevTools();` That's why I'm sure that `.//label[text()='Columns']` exist.

[image]

---

**UPD** I'm connecting to electron application through exposed port, maybe this is kind of issue?

```
    public WebDriver createDriver(DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities) 

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8315");
        options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        options.merge(desiredCapabilities);

        return new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually answer was pretty simple. You need just explicitly declare that you want webview to appear in the list of window handles.

Here is official chromedriver docs [link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities#h.p_ID_106) and capabilities name is **windowTypes**

In java code it will be looked like this

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
List<String> webview = Collections.singletonList("webview");
options.setExperimentalOption("windowTypes", webview);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

//after that you can just switch to is
driver.switchTo().window("yourHandle");

//and work with it as usual
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[text()='Columns']"));
```

Comment: Is there a way to switch to window context in iframe, if I don't have webview, just iframe inside shadow root?

Comment: @lexigren I assume that the code snippet **in question**  was not a lot of help to you?

Comment: @lexigren looks like code snippet in `my question` should help you, because it is standard practice how to switch into iframe that inside shadow-dom