# Microsoft Teams Desktop application Automation with Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, electron

Was following the Article https://applitools.com/blog/automating-electron-applications-using-selenium/ to automate MS Teams Desktop application. Able to start, perform actions on elements, but got to the point when new popup appears and it is a "webview". Would appreciate any advice to find a way to locate elements in the webview, is Selenium able to switch to it? Or some other tool to use for automation this type of applications?

Comment: The solution was simple and described in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63225306/how-to-switch-to-iframe-inside-shadow-dom-with-selenium

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your browser capabilities

`new ChromeOptions().setExperimentalOption("windowTypes", singletonList("webview"))`